# How do I refresh text in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, tkinter

I have a python app on Gnu/Linux. The program enables or disables the camera and microphone from the kernel. The program works fine except for a little problem that I cannot resolve. The program has 4 buttons. There are 2 buttons that enable camera and microphone and two buttons that disable them. There are four texts: `Camera is not loaded`, `Camera is loaded`, `Microphone is loaded` and `Microphone is not loaded`.

PROBLEM:

The problem is that the messages show both texts. It shows `Camera is loaded` and `Camera not loaded`. Example when I open the app for the first time it says Camera not loaded. When I press the button to enable the camera the text says Camera is loaded but the problem is the text camera not loaded is not deleting. It shows both messages `Camera is loaded` and `Camera not loaded`. If I exit from the program and load again the problem solved, It shows only the message `camera is loaded`. I want to refresh the new message without exiting the program and load again.

Can anyone help me to solve that?

Here is Python program:

```py
def update():
    root.after(1000, update)  # run itself again after 1000 ms
    var1()

def var1():
    var1 = StringVar()
    exit_code_cam = os.system("lsmod |grep uvcvideo")
    load = "Camera is loaded"
    notLoad = "Camera not loaded"

    if exit_code_cam == 0:
        l1 = Label(root, textvariable=var1, fg="green")
        l1.place(x=2, y=30)
        var1.set(load)
    else:
        l1 = Label(root, textvariable=var1, fg="red")
        l1.place(x=2, y=10)
        var1.set(notLoad)

def button_add1():
    cam_mic_bash.enable_cam()
    var1()

def button_add3():
    cam_mic_bash.disable_cam()
    var1()

# Define Buttons
button_1 = Button(root, text="Allow camera", width=20, height=5, padx=0, pady=0, command=button_add1)
button_3 = Button(root, text="Block camera", width=20, height=5, padx=0, pady=0, command=button_add3)

# Put the buttons on the screen
button_1.place(x=0, y=75)
button_3.place(x=0, y=150)

# run first time
update()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example by adding your modules (Tkinter .. etc.)?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be placing labels over and over in `var1()`, but instead do it only once and update the stringvar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating new labels over and over again, create the label once and configure it according to your requirements, á la

```
import os
from tkinter import StringVar, Tk, Label, Button

root = Tk()
camera_loaded_stringvar = StringVar()
camera_label = Label(root, textvariable=camera_loaded_stringvar)
camera_label.place(x=2, y=10)

def update_loop():
    root.after(1000, update_loop)  # run itself again after 1000 ms
    update_camera_label()


def update_camera_label():
    is_loaded = os.system("lsmod | grep uvcvideo") == 0
    if is_loaded:
        camera_loaded_stringvar.set("Camera is loaded")
        camera_label.configure(fg="green")
    else:
        camera_loaded_stringvar.set("Camera not loaded")
        camera_label.configure(fg="red")


def button_add1():
    enable_cam()
    update_camera_label()


def button_add3():
    disable_cam()
    update_camera_label()


allow_camera_button = Button(root, text="Allow camera", width=20, height=5, padx=0, pady=0, command=button_add1)
block_camera_button = Button(root, text="Block camera", width=20, height=5, padx=0, pady=0, command=button_add3)

allow_camera_button.place(x=0, y=75)
block_camera_button.place(x=0, y=150)

update_loop()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Now It not show text label at all. Either when enabled or disabled!

Comment: Ah, I forgot the place invocation for the label. You can probably add that back.

Comment: I don't understand. What does code is missing?

Comment: Added the invocation after `camera_label = ...`

Comment: Mate my english is not very well. So I am not expert. Would you like to write the code? I have not idea what you said. I don't understand what can I do?

Comment: I also correct this line. you write ` enable_cam()` This line doen't work I have to change with `cam_mic_bash.enable_cam()`

Comment: You didn't show us an import for `cam_mic_bash` in the first place, so I assumed you could adapt your code accordingly. You can also look at the edit history for my post to see where I added the `place` invocation: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71517819/revisions

Comment: Thank you mate. I appreciated your help!!! have this problem many months ago.